# Height of Isosceles Triangle

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to find the height of the grey trapezoid?
If it is, can you please give me a solution?
[image: Trapezoid]

Comment: don't think so -- different heights are possible. you could find the range for the height though...

Comment: No, it is not possible unless you know something more. The total heigh means nothing because you can make the part above high as you want leaving the grey part untouched.

Comment: You need something more like the Area of the bigger one or something

Comment: No its not. $1+0.75+0.75=2.5$ . Ratio is $1: 2.5$ so ratio of height is $m:n$ where $m$ is height of small trapezium and $n$ of the bigger one above it. And we know $4=\frac{m}{n+m}*4+\frac{n}{n+m}*4$. Not much else we can do.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys